# iOS swift JSON to class object

Tags: ios, json, swift, rest

How can I parse JSON to a class when JSON has multiples arrays?
I'm trying to convert data from REST API to my classes in Swift 2.0, but I can't figure out how to do it properly, anyone can help?

```
/* JSON from REST API
{
  "Name": "New name",
  "Email": "test@test.com",
  "FacebookId": "new facebook Id",
  "Address": "New Address",
  "Photo": "https://graph.facebook.com/novo facebook Id/picture?width=500&height=500",
  "CreditCards": [
    {
      "Id": 5,
      "LastNumber": "3123",
      "Brand": "visa"
    },
    {
      "Id": 6,
      "LastNumber": "3124",
      "Brand": "visa"
    }
  ]
}
```

Class representation in swift?

```
    class Client {
  var fullName: String?
  var email: String?
  var facebookId: String?
  var photo: String?
  var creditCards: [CreditCard]?

  required init(json: JSON) {
    self.fullName = json["FullName"].string
    self.email = json["Email"].string
    self.facebookId = json["FacebookId"].string
    self.photo = json["Photo"].string
    self.creditCards = json["CreditCards"]["Id"]
  }

  required init() {}
}

class CreditCard {
  var Id: Int?
  var lastNumber: String?
  var brand: String?
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at the NSJSONSerialization class and its methods. They do exactly what you need: converting JSON data into arrays, dictionaries, strings and numbers.